# TZInfo::PeriodNotFound XYZ is an invalid local time

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a method called `convert_time_with_zone` and it has been called hundreds of thousands of times, if not millions, over the last few months. However, today it suddenly resulted in an error.

Here's my method:

```
  def convert_time_with_zone(time)
    ActiveSupport::TimeZone.new(time_zone).local_to_utc(time)
  end
```

Here's the error I'm experiencing:

```
[6] pry(#<Assessment>)> current_day
=> 2022-03-06 02:00:00 +0000
[7] pry(#<Assessment>)> future_day
=> 2022-03-13 02:00:00 +0000
[8] pry(#<Assessment>)> convert_time_with_zone(current_day)
=> 2022-03-06 07:00:00 UTC
[9] pry(#<Assessment>)> convert_time_with_zone(future_day)
TZInfo::PeriodNotFound: 2022-03-13 02:00:00 is an invalid local time.
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/tzinfo-2.0.4/lib/tzinfo/timezone.rb:500:in `period_for_local'
Caused by TZInfo::PeriodNotFound: 2022-03-13 02:00:00 is an invalid local time.
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/tzinfo-2.0.4/lib/tzinfo/timezone.rb:500:in `period_for_local'
[10] pry(#<Assessment>)>
```

I don't understand why, in the exact same format as the working one, the other one doesn't work. The only difference between the two is one is March 6th whereas the other is March 13th.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no 2022-03-13 02:00 in that, presumably US, time zone.

That is when daylight savings time "leaps ahead" in the US. On that day the local clock goes from 01:59:59 to 03:00:00.

Similarly, 2022-11-06 01:00 will happen twice when clocks "fall back" making converting local times in that range ambiguous.

Comment: Ahh gotcha, wow... Never saw that one coming, lol. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @LewlSauce |Timezones| always worse than you think.